# Rules for FHA loan availability

Tags: united-states, loans

I'm trying to find the laws on what makes a condo complex available for FHA loans.  I hear it has something to do with the amount of money on reserve and the owner/occupancy ratio.  Does anyone know if there is a copy of these laws online?

Answer (score 1):

This blog posting has some good info: http://www.massrealestatelawblog.com/new-stricter-fha-condominium-lending-regulations-and-guidelines-sure-to-chill/.  I won't duplicate the list in this response, but there are quite a few requirements nowadays.